# Correct usage of Either, Try and Exceptions/ControlThrowable in scala

Tags: scala, error-handling, exception, try-catch, either

In my scala code (libraries as well as applications) I currently use a mixture of `Option` and `Try`, whenever either of both feels more apropriate.

I tend to implement "doSomething"-methods which can succeed with a return value or with a failure with `Try`. That is, they can contain code which *throw*, or, when I detect errors "by hand", I artificially create a `Throwable` and return a `Failure`. The return value of those methods hence is a `Try[ReturnType]`.

Now I read that creating exceptions is somewhat suboptimal, because it creates a stack trace (and hence is slow), which I don't even need. I also saw examples using a subclass of `ControlThrowable`, which don't create a stack trace, however they also don't have a message, and `Try` of course won't catch it.

Now my concrete question would be, should I generally favour `Either` over `Try` when I want to do runtime error-handling / method return values, and use `Try` only in situations where I actually need to *catch* something (e.g. thirdparty code)?
That way I would not have to create clumsy `Throwable`s, but instead only use e.g. strings in `Left` for errors.

So basically:

- `Option`: every day usage for something which plain has a value or not
- `Try`: catching exceptions within methods, but not used as return value
- `Either`: universal return value, containing error (string) or success value

Would this concept work out well, or is there a more viable/common approach?

Comment: You can pretty easily define a subclass of `Throwable` that doesn't create a stack trace via the constructor with `writableStackTrace`.

Comment: there is also the `NoStackTrace` trait in Scala

Comment: Not really an answer, but my own view is that the two relevant choices are `Try` and `Either[Throwable, ?]`, and the decision is largely cultural: choose `Either` if you're using Cats and Cats-associated libraries, consider `Try` otherwise, and be consistent, converting when necessary as early as possible.

Comment: Whatever you do, stay away from `ControlThrowable`. That is intended for internal use only, when the language designers need to mess with control flow in ways that are otherwise not possible.

Comment: There is no such thing as one-ring-to-rule-them-all. Use `Try` (or your own product ADT) where you want a return of Product types and use `Either` if you need a Sum type return.

Comment: Well, the core difference would be that the error-part in `Try` is **always** `Throwable`, but in `Either` it can be anything, and as I pointed out, creating a `Throwable` is what I'd like to avoid. Or in other words: *should* I still create a `Throwable` for transporting error-descriptions in the return value, while the same can be achieved with `Either[String,_]` + right?

Comment: @Travis Brown: What would be the benefit of using `Either[Throwable, ?]` over `Try`?

Comment: @user826955 1) You're working with libraries that use `Either` (e.g. circe), it's easier to interop with non-`Throwable` failure representations, less magic around where exceptions get caught, etc.

Comment: @TravisBrown Why do you want to return Either[Throwable, ?] when your error has not been generated because of a caught Throwable and is enough with a String that describe the error or and, for example, a case class with metadata about the context of the error? He is talking about create an Exception to represent an error.

Comment: Remainder: Scala Throwable is an alias to java.lang.Throwable I always try to avoid native java stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Travis Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665123/correct-usage-of-either-try-and-exceptions-controlthrowable-in-scala#comment96121097_54665123) has stated in the comments, there is no *real* convention and it is largely a cultural thing. Consistency is the most important thing here in order to keep your code readable. I've seen codebases which:

- Use Options to mean "`None` is a success and any `Some(...)` contains the error message"
- Use Try in order to return either a Success containing an empty String or a Failure containing the error message
- Use Either the wrong way around (ie `Either[?, Throwable]`)

Obviously these aren't good practices, but as long as you're consistent it doesn't *really* matter. The convention I personally use both recreationally and at work is:

- **`Option`** for when it's valid for a value to be missing (eg when parsing JSON using playframework).
- **`Try`** when attempting to do something that might fail (unless it's in a Future, in which case I just use `.recover`), where I care about matching the type of exception but also want the result of the Success where available.
- **`Either`** when I don't want to return an Exception/Throwable in my "fail" case (though to be honest this is rare).

Regardless of which of the above I use, I personally think it's best keep it wrapped up for as long as possible. This stops unnecessary Throwables being thrown <sup>(haha)</sup> around in your code, and makes debugging easier as there aren't any hidden `getOrElse` lines returning default values (this can get very annoying in large codebases).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I decided to go as I suggested in my question. Using `Try` for catching exception from thirdparties, and `Either[A, B]` as general return value, with `A` beeing a custom error type with supplementary info. 
`Option`, as "usual", is used whenever the absence of a value is allowed.

And in general I avoid to use exceptions at all, so never throwing or creating them.